# Scrollspy navbar fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js, scrollspy

so I'm building a site with fullPage.js, however I would like to use a custom navbar that I made.
I want the navbar buttons to change when you scroll to the respective section (i.e. if I scroll to contact section, contact button lights up in navbar), like scrollspy in bootstrap.

How can I go about this?

Thanks a lot! I've been googling for hours but I just can't find an answer.

**EDIT: for anyone that may run in to this problem, here's what I did**

I added an id to my ul that contained my navbar items, and added 
    `data-menuanchor="your anchor goes here"`

then, in the fullpage js initalization, added the menu option

```
`$('#fullpage').fullpage({
anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage',        
'lastPage'],
menu: '#id of your navbar ul'});`
```

Then I went into the fullpagejs css file and edited this part to appear how I wanted it when section was active

```
fp-nav ul li a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li a.active span,
fp-nav ul li:hover a.active span,
.fp-slidesNav ul li:hover a.active span{

background-color: #3b8d37;
color:white;
```

}

cheers to @Kasabucki Alexandr for quick and helpful reply

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out  documentation of fullPage.js. Option: menu.

```
<ul id="myMenu">
  <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">Первый раздел</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Второй раздел</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Третий раздел</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#fourthPage">Четвёртый раздел</a></li>
```

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#myMenu'});
```

It looks like you are looking for.

Also you can use afterSlideLoad callback:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],

afterSlideLoad: function( anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){
    var loadedSlide = $(this);

    //первый слайд второго раздела
    if(anchorLink == 'secondPage' && slideIndex == 1){
        alert("Первый слайд загружен");
    }

    //второй слайд второго раздела (supposing #secondSlide is the
    //привязка для второго раздела
    if(index == 2 && slideIndex == 'secondSlide'){
        alert("Второй слайд загружен");
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Thank you!! Using the menu option and modifying the fullpagejs css file a bit did the trick.